# How to run a function when Materialize.css autocomplete selected to pass the selected value to another function?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, materialize

I am using Materialize autocomplete for my webapp. I need the autocomplete value to be passed to another function which then passed to another function to look up corresponding values and return. Any idea How i go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `onAutocomplete` option

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
      data: {
        "Apple": null,
        "Microsoft": null,
        "Google": 'https://placehold.it/250x250'
      },
      onAutocomplete:function(data){
       // write your code
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks @Sarath. I'm very new to javascript with limited knowledge. I'm following this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhAmyLukD6o and wanted the autocomplete to be used same way the dropdown is used to get the estimated cost if a specific option is selected. Hope i have managed to explain properly here.

Comment: can you share the code in jsfiddle or jsbin so that I can check and help you better

Comment: Dont know how to do that. here is the code i'm looking at: function populateAgentNames(agents){

  var autocomplete = document.getElementById('agentnameinput');
  M.Autocomplete.init(autocomplete, { data: agents });
  

}

Comment: Hey @Sarath, as per the video i am using another function to provide the list of autocomplete options so its not hardcoded in, given that as soon as I add the onAutocomplete function it does not work anymore. Feels like its messing with initialising all together as even the date picker stops working. :-(

Comment: you need to get the data from the function then initialize the autocomplete. check the this link: http://jsfiddle.net/72vc9zke/1/